# Remove Footer without removing the header

Tags: xetex, header-footer, fancyhdr

I created a header and footer using fancyhdr. I want to remove the footer from a particular page without touching the header.  I tried changing the page styles but nothing worked. any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a style where you only clear the footer:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Let's populate headers and footers
% just to show the effect
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Right header}
\fancyhead[C]{Center header}
\fancyhead[L]{Left header}
\fancyfoot[R]{Right footer}
\fancyfoot[C]{Center footer}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer}

% This is what you really need to add
\fancypagestyle{nofooter}{%
  \fancyfoot{}%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}

\kant[1-4]

\thispagestyle{nofooter}

\kant[5-8]

\end{document}
```

You'll see that on page two only the headers appear, but the footer returns on page three.